# Cleaning scraped data Python

Tags: python-3.x, excel

I trying to learn how to scrape a website but I'm not able to figure out how to "clean" the data when importing the output to Excel. 
Here is the code I used:

[image]

However, when opening the Excel file, the output is in need of some cleaning:

[image]

I assume that I should put ".text" somewhere put I don't know where. I tried adding .text as show below but it resulted in "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'"

```
for i in links:
    index.append([i.attrs['title']]).text
    summary.append([i.attrs["aria-label"]]).text
```

Comment: Don't post pictures of code as an image, always as text! And for your question, try `index.append(i.attrs['title'])` without the `[ ]` brackets. The same for `summary`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're telling Python to append a list to the `index` and `summary` lists by having extra brackets.
Try this instead:

```
for i in links:
    index.append(i.attrs['title'])
    summary.append(i.attrs["aria-label"])
```

You're still going to have some ugly information in the summary column. You can use [replace](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=replace#str.replace) or [RegEx](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) to clean this up. If you provide an output that you desire, I can edit this to include the appropriate code for replacing characters.

Also, `index` is the name of a method in Python, so I would choose a different list name for that.